# stringr: replace string by supplying pattern through a character vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

Here is my data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~A,  ~B,
        "C", "G",
        "D", "H",
        "E", "I",
        "F", "J")

value1 <- "D"

value2 <- "C"
```

And, in variable A, I want to replace D and C with "m" and "n", something like this, but it's not working!

```
df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(c(value1 = "m", value2 = "n")))
```

My desired output is:

```
df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(c("D" = "m", "C" = "n")))
```

But instead of supplying "D" and "C" manually, I want to programmatically supply these, something in line with...using value1 and value2.

How should I do that?

Comment: Would this work: `df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(setNames(c("m","n"), c(value1, value2))))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `setNames` to set the names of `m` and `n` like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(setNames(c("m","n"), c(value1, value2))))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  A     B     X    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 C     G     n    
#2 D     H     m    
#3 E     I     E    
#4 F     J     F
```

And then checking that it's equal to your desired result:

```
identical(
          df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(c("D" = "m", "C" = "n"))),
          df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(setNames(c("m","n"), c(value1, value2)))))
#[1] TRUE
```

I also included the other packages you use: dplyr and stringr

Comment: @Geet, great! I think it has to do with how R will evaluate the names you try to pass. For example, this doesn't substitute in the value for value1: `c(value1 = "c")`

Comment: Can it also extend to say, df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(setNames(c("m","n"), c(value1, value2))), "E" = "o")? i.e. two values replaced with value2 and value2 variables and one without?

Comment: Yes, try `df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all( c(setNames(c("m","n"), c(value1, value2)), "E" = "o")))`

Comment: Fantastic...that is exactly what I was looking for! Eureka!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of creating a named vector and use it as replacement vector.

```
replacementVector <- c("m","n")
names(replacementVector) <- c("D","C")
```

Now, use the `replacementVector` in `dplyr` chain along with `ifelse` as:

```
df %>% mutate(X = ifelse(is.na(replacementVector[A]), A, replacementVector[A]))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# A     B     X    
# <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 C     G     n    
# 2 D     H     m    
# 3 E     I     E    
# 4 F     J     F
```

**Data:**

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~A,  ~B,
  "C", "G",
  "D", "H",
  "E", "I",
  "F", "J")
```

Comment: Interesting! Good to know a non-str_replace_all solution to this problem. Never thought of that!

Comment: Yes. Named vector works on similar line meaning matches name to return value.

Answer (score 1):

As is vectorized over string and replacement if you put all the values in the same vector you can just run

```
df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(c("C","D"), c("m","n")))
```

Comment: It really good to know this solution. Thanks! In my program, I needed to supply C and D through a character vector.

Comment: you could just do: `values <- c("C","D"); 
df %>% mutate(X = A %>% str_replace_all(values, c("m","n")))`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `chartr`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(X = chartr('DC', 'mn', A))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   A     B     X    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 C     G     n    
#2 D     H     m    
#3 E     I     E    
#4 F     J     F
```

Comment: Base function could do it so easily. Really helpful!